# How to add the commit's description to the discord webhook bot messages?

Tags: github, bots, webhooks, discord

I followed this tutorial to create a Webhook between Github and Discord.
https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668

Everything worked as expected and the bot is updating the chat just fine.

Despite searching in the Docs 
( https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook ), I
could not find how to configure the bot so it also displays the commit's description.

I don't really know if this is possible, can someone point me how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discord GitHub webhook does display the first line of the commit which `git` typically treats as a summary.

The [GitHub `push` webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) publishes a json document containing fields such as `head`, `refs`, and a `commits` array with fields such as `message` and `author`.

However, the [default Discord webhook](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) expects a simpler json document with just a `content` field for the message body. This webhook will reject a GitHub `push` document.

However Discord also provides a special [GitHub webhook](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-githubcompatible-webhook) that understands the payload of the [GitHub `push` webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent). You've set this up but as noted only displays the first line of the commit. There doesn't seem to be any way to customize it.

If you want to display the full commit message, you'll need a custom bot that can receive the GitHub `push` event, format a new json document in the form expected by the default Discord webhook, and send it to the Discord API.

There is already [an app](https://github.com/Falconerd/discord-bot-github) that does this. The developer has abandoned it in favor of the official Discord GitHub webhook but left it running for now. It's easy to integrate and it does display the full commit message. It does require a public GitHub repository however.

Comment: thanks Jeff, I imagined that was the case, but I was too lazy to search it out!